# Adding KML Layer to Google Map embedded in a Blogger Page

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, blogger

I have a Blogger page with an embedded Google map which works fine. When I try to use Google's Javascript API to add a KML layer on top of the map the map becomes entirely black apart from the navigation controls. If I set the kml layer back to null the underlying map appears again.

I have tested the exact same code in a local environment and it works fine. So the issue is with embedding the code within a Blogger page.

Below is my html and js. Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

Note that the example kml file I'm using below is just a skeleton without any placemarkers, but I've tried it with other kmls and got the same result.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map-canvas { 
            height: 480px; 
            width: 500px; 
            margin: 0px; 
            padding: 0px 
        } 
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3" type="text/javascript"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function initializeMap() { 
            var centre = new google.maps.LatLng(35.5906421,37.6945915); 
            var mapOptions = { 
                zoom: 3, 
                center: centre, 
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            } 

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions); 
            var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({ 
                url: 'http://trackmytour.com/Dpxc9.kml', 
                preserveViewport: true 
            }); 

            layer.setMap(map); 
        } 

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap); 

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>
        Here is where I'll be tracking my progress.<br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </p>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you add a link to your blogger page where you attempted to embed the map?

Comment: [Your KML doesn't contain any useful information](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A//trackmytour.com/Dpxc9.kml).  Your problem is probably the blogger CSS or infrastructure.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth here is a link to the Blogger page: http://doshgoeseast.blogspot.co.uk/p/map-for-big-trip.html

Comment: @geocodezip, I know the KML doesn't contain any information but that is not related to the problem; I've tried it with other populated KMLs and had the same issue. Absolutely agree that the issue is with the Blogger CSS or infrastructure, the problem (for me) is narrowing it down further in order that I may find a way to work around it.

Comment: Without actual data in the KML file we can't be of any help.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth Sorry I disagree, the data (or lack of it) has nothing to to with the issue. It's some CSS interference from the Blogger template with google's maps api when adding a kml layer. I observe exactly the same effect whether there is data in the KML or not. If I don't add the KML layer the issue goes away. I've worked around it for now by putting the map in an iframe with the HTML hosted on Google Drive.

Comment: Then that means when I checked your link, you had already changed it. We'll need a reproducible page to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Thanks for checking and trying to help. I needed to implement a workaround a couple of days ago as the blog has gone 'live' now. It's a travel blog and I needed that page to track my progress so I had to put in an ugly iframe hack. 

It's a bit hard for me to set up a test page for you now as I'm on the road and living on a bicycle and out of a tent! If I get a chance at some point when I have a good internet connection I'll try to make something available.